# How can I determine the OS from an AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I get the AWS instance information by using the AWS-SDK.EC2.describeInstances, here is one element in the array:

```
 stdout: {
 stdout: AmiLaunchIndex: 0,
 stdout: ImageId: 'ami-00d03ffa3b3757af2',
 stdout: InstanceId: 'i-09167c582a8d016ae',
 stdout: InstanceType: 'r5.4xlarge',
 stdout: KeyName: 'interos-prod',
 stdout: LaunchTime: 2019-08-20T18:01:14.000Z,
 stdout: Monitoring: { State: 'disabled' },
 stdout: Placement: {
 stdout: AvailabilityZone: 'us-west-2c',
 stdout: GroupName: '',
 stdout: Tenancy: 'default'
 stdout: },
 stdout: PrivateDnsName: 'ip-xxx-31-9-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal',
 stdout: PrivateIpAddress: '172.31.9.226',
 stdout: ProductCodes: [],
 stdout: PublicDnsName: 'ec2-54-xxx-226-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com',
 stdout: PublicIpAddress: '54.201.xxx.xxx',
 stdout: State: { Code: 16, Name: 'running' },
 stdout: StateTransitionReason: '',
 stdout: SubnetId: 'subnet-f3ee49a9',
 stdout: VpcId: 'vpc-7e338d07',
 stdout: Architecture: 'x86_64',
 stdout: BlockDeviceMappings: [ [Object] ],
 stdout: ClientToken: '',
 stdout: EbsOptimized: true,
 stdout: EnaSupport: true,
 stdout: Hypervisor: 'xen',
 stdout: ElasticGpuAssociations: [],
 stdout: ElasticInferenceAcceleratorAssociations: [],
 stdout: NetworkInterfaces: [ [Object] ],
 stdout: RootDeviceName: '/dev/sda1',
 stdout: RootDeviceType: 'ebs',
 stdout: SecurityGroups: [ [Object] ],
 stdout: SourceDestCheck: true,
 stdout: Tags: [ [Object], [Object] ],
 stdout: VirtualizationType: 'hvm',
 stdout: CpuOptions: { CoreCount: 8, ThreadsPerCore: 2 },
 stdout: CapacityReservationSpecification: { CapacityReservationPreference: 'open' },
 stdout: HibernationOptions: { Configured: false },
 stdout: Licenses: []
 stdout: },
```

anybody know? I am looking to figure out if it's ubuntu or amazon-linux, or whatever the OS is .

Answer (score 0):

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html

You should be able to query the Image ID on line 3? "ImageId: 'ami-00d03ffa3b3757af2'" --> `aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-00d03ffa3b3757af2` and the description should provide the information you need

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do a query on the AMI(Amazon Machine Image) Id to get more information.

Try this

```
describe-images --image-ids yourImageId
```

In the response you can look for `kernel-id`

Comment: I am not seeing kernel-id or KernelId anywhere unfortunately

Comment: You can check 'platform' tag if it is a windows box